# What is the gold token used for in Kitty Paw?

Tags: components

Just opened our game of Kitty Paw and there is a gold paper/cardboard token not listed on the game components, does anyone know what this is? I also don't see it mentioned anywhere in the rules.

[image: Gold Token]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a mistake. When I checked the unboxing video on BGG there wasn't any token looking anything like that in the game parts.

Comment: It is in this picture (also on BGG) https://boardgamegeek.com/image/3535264/kitty-paw

Comment: Yes. I didn't see that before. Boy, now I'm really scratching my head on this one!